# Dojo: set content pane widgetid attribute

Tags: dojo

How can I set content pane widgetid attribute when?

```
new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
    content: "<p>Optionally set new content now</p>",
    style: "height:125px",
    // I can set id, but widgetid will differ
    id: 'someId',
    // no effect
    widgetid: 'myWidgetId',
    // still fail
    widgetId: 'how can I set you, God damn it?!'
}
```

I need it for content pane finding with dijit.byId(), as this method gets the element by it's widgetid attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already passing an Id when building your widget programmatically.

In your case, you should be able to retrieve your widget through :

```
dijit.byId('someId');
```

The id needed by dijit.byId is in the "id" property of your widget, not in the widgetId property.

See : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/info.html#locating-widgets

Answer (score 1):

You could set the widgetId attribute after creating the widget.

```
var w = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
    content: "<p>Optionally set new content now</p>",
    style: "height:125px"
}

w.domNode.setAttribute("widgetId", "customWidgetId");
```